# text encoding in ftp download app causing errors

Tags: java, utf-8, ftp-client

I have created a script to download files from an ftp endpoint. I was assured that the files would be in utf-8 encoding but upon downloading and parsing the xml, we encounter bad formatting. The process is to download the file, convert the xml to json and parse and convert to a different format. What we see after converting to json is for example the following which appears instead of chinese/hindi/arabic characters:

> "Size": 3227,
> "Title": "??? ???? ????? ?? ???? ?? 5 ??? ?? ??? ?? ?? ???? ?? ????????? ?? ???? ???? ??????-Pakistan new army chief

The code snippet is the following:

```
        ftp.connect("xx.xxx.xxx.xx");
        ftp.login("xxxx", "xxxxx");

        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ...
        String remoteFile1 = ftp.printWorkingDirectory() + "/" + file.getName();
        File downloadFile1 = new File(destFolder + "/" + "/" + file.getName());
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.flush();
        outputStream1.close();
         ....
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
        String xml = sw.toString();
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(4);
        jsonMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);...
```

Can someone advise how to ensure the encoding can be changed to output the correct format for foreign characters?

Comment: [check this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType-int-)

Comment: "What we see after converting to json is for example the following which appears instead of chinese/hindi/arabic characters" Appears where? Are you sure you're checking with a software that can display chinese/hindi/arabic characters?

Comment: Thanks; tried it and same issue persists.

Comment: @m0skit0 I see now that the downloaded file appears that way as well in a browser even though its saved with utf-8 encoding

Comment: Did you check the actual binary is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Manually downloaded the ftp file with filezilla and tried opening it in browser as well. How else should I view the actual binary? Do you mean at the outputstream line in debug mode?

Comment: Try `docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("foo.xml"), "UTF-8"))));` Can't see if those brackets are right but you get the idea... Would help to link to a file we can test that shows the problem

Comment: What tool and font are you using to render those _"chinese/hindi/arabic characters"_ in your JSON file?

Comment: Thanks for everyones response; the file at the source is the issue and we are still waiting on a fix for that. But in the meantime, I have a question on whether its possible to read a file with bad encoding and write out a new file with that content in the correct encoding?

Comment: Things are rarely *im*possible but you want to avoid attempting that as you will probably be forever tweaking it

Comment: agree; temporary workarounds do tend to create additional headaches. Thanks